# Skype does not sign me in on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, skype, javascript

When I try to sign in to Skype, I get a message about a JavaScript problem. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgZld.png).

I already tried re-installing Skype and deleting all lock files as well as *shared.xml* but the problem persists.

What can the reason be?

Thanks in advance.